# Skype is still uppercasing even with disabled spell check

Tags: windows-10, skype, spell-check, autocorrect

Even though I disabled every possible spell correction, Skype is still uppercasing automatically ("cyber monday" becomes "cyber Monday", etc.)

I want the freedom to write all lower case in my chat since my friends write this way too, but Skype does NOT ALLOW me this, which is extremly frustrating. Especially when only certain words are uppercased, it looks like I have no idea about correct spelling at all.

I reported this issue already about a year ago to the Skype team, but it looks like it just got ignored.

How can I stop Skype once and for all from changing my writing?

[image]